# Convert QCQP into SOCP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, qcqp, second-order-cone-programming

I have to solve the following optimization problem

[image]

How can I convert this quadratically-constrained quadratic program (QCQP) into a second-order cone program (SOCP)? Is this QCQP  convex?

Comment: Where does this come from?